# Is there a way to apply color filter on whole screen using Android's Accessibility Services?

Tags: android, android-studio, accessibility, accessibilityservice, colormatrix

Thing is, i'm currently trying to create a tool for legally blind people (specially with Retinitis Pigmentosa). They would benefit from some kind of color invertion (A smart one). To achieve this, i thought of applying some color matrices over the screen so the apps that aren't compatible with OS's dark mode can still be dark.

I have done some research and i'm not sure if this is possible. I know that normally you can't access other app/system views because of signature permissions, but is there a way to achieve this using the accessibility services?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to affect the display pipeline from an accessibility service that's why there are various color corrections available directly as Android features.